# Need help on Codeigniter framework .htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working on a script which is developed by another developer. He did't used base_path() in url's, when i configured script on my local machine(xampp) i am redirecting outside of the project directory.

```
Project directory /testing/

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/quick_register.css" />
<a href="/account/">Account</account>


online it works perfectly but when i click on this link local system it redirects me      

http://localhost/xampp

it should redirect me on http://localhost/testing/account

here is online .htaccess rule


#URL Re-writing
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

Thanks

Comment: try like this: RewriteBase /testing   in your .htaccess file

Comment: i have already tried this but it is not working.

Comment: in online how is url. menas for access pages index.php is there in url or not?

Comment: url is like this www.abc.com and in url there is no index.php

Comment: also it is not loading the css file.

Answer (score 0):

As your project is under "testing" folder you need to update the rewritebase according to your project location.
Try something like below with your htaccess file:

```
#URL Re-writing
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing
```

Try with/without trailing slashes, it should work.